AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', - Data not added to database
My react ,MySQL crud app doesnt add data to the MySQL database.
in my student.js file which is the file that opens in localhost:3000
There is my button "Add +"
<Link to="/create" className='btn btn-success'> Add + </Link>


in my CreateStudent.js
file (used to create a student)
i have the below submit function
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/create', {name, email})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        navigate('/');
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h2>Add Student</h2>
            <div className='mb-2'>
                <label htmlFor="">Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Enter Name' className='form-control' 
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
            </div>

            <div className='mb-2'>
                <label htmlFor="">Email</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder='Enter Email' className='form-control' 
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            </div>

            <button className='btn btn-success'>Submit</button>

         </form>


in my server.js file
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();    
app.use(express.json());    
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "",
    database : "crud"
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    //res.json("Helloooooo from backend");
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
    db.query(sql, (err, data) => {
       if(err) return res.json("Error");
       return res.json(data);
         
    })
})
    
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO student ('Name','Email') VALUES (?)";
    const values = [
        req.body.name,
        req.body.email
    ]
    db.query(sql, [values], (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json("Errorrr");
        return res.json(data);
    })
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
   console.log("Listening....");   

})


It also gives this error
POST http://localhost:8080/create 404 (Not Found)
When I press the "Submit" button nothing happens page stays the same.
Can someone help me with this ?

What is handleSubmit supposed to be bound to?

INSERT INTO student ('Name','Email') VALUES (?) - Where is the second placeholder for Email? - It also could be useful to log the actual error(s) - if(err) return res.json("Errorrr");
